# Possibility of external functions as nullable guards?

Tags: c#, .net-core, c#-8.0, nullable-reference-types

C# 8 introduced nullable reference types, which is a very cool feature. Now if you expect to get nullable values you have to write so-called guards:

```cs
object? value = null;
if (value is null)
{
  throw new ArgumentNullException();
}
…
```

These can be a bit repetitive. What I am wondering is if it is possible to avoid writing this type of code for every variable, but instead have a guard-type `static void` function that throws exception if value is `null` or just returns if value is not `null`. Or is this too hard for compiler to infer? Especially if it's external library/package?

Comment: It may be repetitive, but it's code you should have been writing anyway. The point of this new feature is so you *don't* have nullable references.

Comment: You can always use properties!

Comment: The question is unclear. This code isn't a guard in the first place, it silently ignores null values, just as it would in any previous version. A guard *throws* if the value is invalid, eg `var v=value??throw new ArgumentNullException();` or returns false in a `TryXXX` method. If you *want* something to be null, you don't need to guard it. What are you trying to do?

Comment: If your method can simply do nothing, consider putting the code so wrapped in a method of whatever type `value` is so you can invoke it as `value?.Method()`, which does nothing if `value` is `null`. That would be much cleaner than sprinkling this "return" pattern everywhere if this is a common thing in your codebase. It would not be in most; checking and throwing an exception is much more common. There's a [proposal up](https://github.com/dotnet/csharplang/issues/2145) for simplifying that specifically.

Comment: The code block indeed should have specified to throw exception rather return.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There are a few things you can do.

You can use `[DoesNotReturnIf(...)]` in your guard method, to indicate that it throws if a particular condition is true or false, for example:

```
public static class Ensure
{
    public static void True([DoesNotReturnIf(false)] bool condition)
    {
        if (!condition)
        {
             throw new Exception("!!!");   
        }
    }
}
```

Then:

```
public void TestMethod(object? o)
{
    Ensure.True(o != null);
    Console.WriteLine(o.ToString()); // No warning
}
```

This [works because](https://github.com/dotnet/csharplang/blob/master/meetings/2019/LDM-2019-05-15.md#flow-attributes):

> `[DoesNotReturnIf(bool)]`: Placed on a bool parameter. Code after the call is unreachable if the parameter has the specified bool value

---

Alternatively, you can declare a guard method like this:

```
public static class Ensure
{
    public static void NotNull([NotNull] object? o)
    {
        if (o is null)   
        {
            throw new Exception("!!!");
        }
    }
}
```

And use it like this:

```
public void TestMethod(object? o)
{
    Ensure.NotNull(o);
    Console.WriteLine(o.ToString()); // No warning
}
```

This [works because](https://github.com/dotnet/csharplang/blob/master/meetings/2019/LDM-2019-05-15.md#simple-postconditions):

> `[NotNull]`: For outputs (ref/out parameters, return values), the output will not be null, even if the type allows it. **For inputs (by-value/in parameters) the value passed is known not to be null when we return.**

[SharpLab with examples](https://sharplab.io/#v2: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)

---

Of course, the real question is *why* you want to do this. If you don't expect `value` to be `null`, then declare it as `object?`, rather than `object` -- that's the point of having NRTs.

Comment: This is still a lot of boiler plate code, this is the stuff nullable references is supposed to remove.

Comment: @DavidG It's no more boilerplate-y than `if (arg == null) throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(arg))`. Some people prefer to put those sorts of checks into utility methods, and my answers explains the attributes needed to do this. NRTs don't remove the need to have null-checks. Anyway, the OP asked whether it's possible to do this and have the compiler infer the right things, and my answer explains how to do this. I'm not passing judgement on *why* the OP asked this.

Comment: I'm not judging either, hence no voting, I'm just explaining that nullable references shouldn't be used like this.

Comment: Maybe they shouldn't but if I for example have generic method with no constraint for generic type it warns about possible null dereference. Still trying out the nullable thing so not sure how to approach is certain scenarios.

Comment: @Hoffs for generics you often need to start using the attributes `AllowNull`, `NotNull`, `MaybeNull`, etc. They're documented in the LDM minutes I linked.

Comment: It's worth also noting that if you're using Microsoft Code Analysis (e.g., [`Microsoft.CodeAnalysis`](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.CodeAnalysis)), _and_ you're storing your reusable guard methods in an external library, then you'll _additionally_ need to annotate your parameters with `[ValidatedNotNull]` to satisfy its validation checks. Code Analysis is able to detect this for local methods, but not for external classes; as such, it requires the additional hint. This may be resolved in a future release, once Code Analysis is updated to be fully aware of C#'s nullability context.

Answer (score 0):

There is a [Guard Clauses library](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Ardalis.GuardClauses) by [Steve Ardalis](https://ardalis.com/) that I think can help you with this situation.
You can do things like:

- `Guard.Against.Null` (throws if input is null)
- `Guard.Against.NullOrEmpty` (throws if string or array input is null or empty)
- `Guard.Against.NullOrWhiteSpace` (throws if string input is null, empty or whitespace)
- `Guard.Against.OutOfRange` (throws if `integer/DateTime/enum` input is outside a provided range)
- `Guard.Against.OutOfSQLDateRange` (throws if `DateTime` input is outside the valid range of SQL Server DateTime values)
- `Guard.Against.Zero` (throws if number input is zero)

In this [blog post](http://dontcodetired.com/blog/post/Simplifying-Parameter-Null-and-Other-Checks-with-the-GuardClauses-Library) [Jason Roberts](http://dontcodetired.com/blog) made a quick explanation of the library too.

There is another [Guard Class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.toolkit.diagnostics.guard?view=win-comm-toolkit-dotnet-stable) in the **`Microsoft.Toolkit.Diagnostics`** namespace but probably is not viable in all the use cases that will depend if wanna add that dependency to the project or not.