# Identify method to C#8 as a nullable checker?

Tags: c#, nullable

I often use extension methods to check method arguments

```
void MyMethod(string? test)
{
    Require.NotNull(test, nameof(test));
    // Same as
    // if (test == null) throw new ArgumentNullExeception(nameof(test))

    ...
}
```

When enabling C# 8's `nullables` however, the compiler does not think I've checked the argument for null when using the extension method.

Is there a way to identify the extension method `Require.NotNull` as a `nullable` checker?

Comment: If data is from a datebase you may need to use DBNULL.Value.

Comment: That's not an extension method.

Comment: To clarify, `Require.NotNull` is the extension method.

Comment: I don't think semantic analysis checks method calls to see how a parameter is used. I would expect that could be an expensive task--think about if your guard method called another guard method that called another guard method....etc.

Comment: I think there was some discussion on GitHub to have some kind of `DoesNotReturnIfNull` attribute or something to annotate this kind of methods. I can't find it now, though

Comment: [`NotNullAttribute`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.codeanalysis.notnullattribute?view=netcore-3.1)?

Comment: @MikeWard That’s not what “extension method” means in .NET. Terminology aside that’s a nice question.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Possibility of external functions as nullable guards?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58411013/possibility-of-external-functions-as-nullable-guards)

Answer (score 4):

There is [ongoing work in roslyn#36039](https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/issues/36039) to eventually allow authors to annotate their methods in a way that gives back nullable information to the compiler. There are some features currently in preview but I don’t know the exact state.

However, I would question your approach here: If the first thing you do in your method is to check against null and effectively throw an exception, then passing a null value to your method is **not** a valid input. So your method should not be annotated in a way that it would accept null.

You rather want to mark it so that it does not accept null, so the compiler will properly tell you where you are calling the method with a potential null value.

Comment: That issue is about method bodies -- the work to allow you to annotate your own method signatures, and how this affects code which uses those methods, is complete (even if tweaks are ongoing)

Comment: @canton7 Yeah, you’re right, it’s already possible now. Thanks for your link on the question, I have closed the question since it is answered very well over there.

Answer (score 1):

No. But to sort of tell this to the compiler, after this line:

```
Require.NotNull(test, nameof(test));
```

You should refer to ***test*** as ***test!*** since you are sure it won't be null anymore.

Still, @Poke is right with the proposal to remove the ***?*** from your parameter list.