# Is there any way I can make ReSharper aware of a custom null checker used by my team?

Tags: c#, resharper

I've recently joined a new project, and our data access layer has a utility method that takes a list of objects and throws if any of them are null, which is normally called at the top of the method. It's pretty handy, except that ReSharper has no idea what it does and thus shows a bunch of "Possible NullReferenceException" warnings in the methods that use it. Is there any way to configure it to know that this method ensures that the objects passed to it aren't null?

Comment: Maybe the [`[DoesNotReturnIf]` attribute](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58411013/possibility-of-external-functions-as-nullable-guards)

Comment: You might need to add attributes to that null checker. If you can't, there is a way to add a separate xml or json file (I forget which) with external annotations, check this link for more information - https://www.jetbrains.com/help/resharper/Code_Analysis__External_Annotations.html